# Cases when tarantool yields

Tags: tarantool

i'm newbie in tarantool and want to ask general question about implicit yelds. At documentation:

"There are implicit yields: every data-change operation or network-access causes an implicit yield, and every statement that goes through the tarantool client causes an implicit yield."

1) What does it mean "every statement that goes through the tarantool client" ? Will be better to get more information about it case. Is it about connectors or common client ?

2) Will be tarantool yelds in data-change operation if WAL log is switched off by setting wal_mode to none ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Poor wording in the documentation. Network/disk IO yields. If you're using `box.begin()` and `box.commit()`, then Disk IO must not yield control to another fiber, until `box.commit()`.

2) Tarantool won't yield, if `insert`/`delete`/`update`/`upsert` executed, but `wal_mode = 'none'`.